# Responsively center a grid of squares

Tags: html, css, grid, center

I'm not really sure on how to explain this problem as I'm still relatively new to coding.

I currently have a line of 7 square divs that sit 'inline' on desktop. As the screen changes however, I would like these divs to drop via floating, but have the row itself remain centered.

Eg.

What happens (if &=edge of screen, and #=blank space) =

**Desktop View**
&# 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/#&

**Shrinked View**
&# 1/2/3/4 #####& 
&# 5/6/7 #######&

What I would like to happen:

**Shrinked View**
&###1/2/3/4##& 
&####5/6/7####&

https://jsfiddle.net/48942Lor/ - Full code.

> CSS

```
#grid-container {width:40%;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}

.grid-image {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

> HTML

```
<section id="grid-container">
<div class="grid-image" id="red"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="orange"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="yellow"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="green"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="blue"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="indigo"></div>
<div class="grid-image" id="violet"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because of `float:left`. Removing that works nicely. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48942Lor/2/).

Answer (score 0):

By removing the CSS under `.grid-image` which says `float:left;`,it would align everything as centered. 
Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/48942Lor/3/

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
/*Color Settings - DO NOT TOUCH OR ADD CODE */

#red {
  background-color: red
}
#orange {
  background-color: orange
}
#yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
#green {
  background-color: green
}
#blue {
  background-color: blue
}
#indigo {
  background-color: indigo
}
#violet {
  background-color: violet
}
/*End of Color Settings - DO NOT TOUCH OR ADD CODE */

/*Outer Container Settings */

#grid-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
/*End of Outer Container Settings */

.grid-image {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section id="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-image" id="red"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="orange"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="yellow"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="green"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="indigo"></div>
  <div class="grid-image" id="violet"></div>
</section>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/53f7ng8y/)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, remove

```
float:left;
```

from .grid-image